# Using transformations that involve multiple predictors in linear regression

Tags: data-transformation, linear-model, feature-engineering

Is it legitimate to arbitrarily combine predictors when setting up a linear model as long as the model is still linear in the parameters? Some examples:
$$
Y_{i}=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}\log(X_{i1} + X_{i2}) +\beta _{2}X_{i1}+\beta _{3}X_{i2} + \varepsilon_i\qquad i=1,\ldots ,n
$$
$$
Y_{i}=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}\log(X_{i1} + \exp(X_{i2} + \sqrt{X_{i3}}) +\beta _{2}X_{i1}+\beta _{3}X_{i2}+\varepsilon_i\qquad i=1,\ldots ,n
$$
I have never seen models with complicated predictor transformations involving more than one predictor so I am a bit skeptical.

Comment: What do you mean by legitimate?  It is just feature engineering which of course you can do, now would you want to interpret any of the goop? Probably not unless they are specific metrics or established KPIs.  But there certainly are times where stuff like this may help prediction power.

Comment: Of course such transformations should only be used when they are implied by some theory, for example. I was just wondering if these transformations contradict some principles of linear regression, which seems to be not that case then.

Comment: Yep you are in the clear, all the stuff can just be rewritten as a different X as long as you can pull the coefficient out and keep it 'linear in parameters'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terms such as $\log(X_{i1} + X_{i2})$ is just a specific data (or feature) transformation, and there is nothing mathematically or statistically wrong in doing so, assuming it makes sense in the modeling context. The model is still a linear model.

So just go ahead and do this, if it makes sense otherwise in your context.